# Bolivia / Brazil Transit Visas

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, brazil, bolivia

I plan to travel from Mumbai to Bolivia. My current itinerary is:

1. Mumbai to Dubai on Emirates (0430 - 0600 03APR)
2. Dubai to Sao Paulo, Brazil on Emirates (0905 - 1700 03APR)
3. Sao Paulo to Viru Viru airport on Boliviana (1835 - 2025 03APR)

[image: picture of itinerary]

Does an Indian Passport Holder require a Bolivian visa or will visa be on arrival?

Secondly, does this itinerary require a transit visa at Sao Paulo airport?

Last question, will baggage be through-checked until Bolivia?

Comment: Can you please write out the airports and the times? I can only see a coloured bar. And those who can't see pictures can not see it at all.

Comment: Is that a single ticket?

Answer (score 2):

TIMATIC States :

> > Bolivia - Destination Visa
> > Visa required.
>
> Visas can be obtained before departure at http://www.rree.gob.bo/formvisas/
>
> Passengers can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 90 days.
> They must have:
>
> - a passport valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date; and
> - a printed flight itinerary; and
> - a printed proof of sufficient funds; and
> - a passport photo 4x4cm white background; and
> - an invitation letter issued by the Bolivian Immigration Authorities (DIGEMIG); or
> - a printed hotel reservation. Payable in cash only.

For Brazil :

> > Brazil - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required. TWOV (Transit Without Visa)
>
> Passengers with a connecting flight booked **on the same ticket**
> in transit.
>
> This TWOV facility does not apply at Curitiba (CWB), Florianopolis (FLN), Porto Alegre (POA), Porto Seguro (BPS) or Salvador (SSA).

---

Make sure to also know about the COVID requirements for Bolivia

As of March 18th 2023 :

> Passengers must have:
>
> - a negative COVID-19 RT-PCR test taken at most 72 hours before departure from the first embarkation point; or
> - a negative COVID-19 antigen test taken at most 48 hours before departure from the first embarkation point; or
> - a COVID-19 vaccination certificate showing that they were fully vaccinated at least 14 days before arrival.
>
> This does not apply to passengers younger than 5 years.
>
> Passengers must present a "Declaracion Jurada del viajero para el
> seguimiento COVID-19" upon arrival.